# In TypeScript, infer that a dynamic argument is the argument of the dynamic function

Tags: typescript

I'm writing jest tests for a websocket message handler.  I have the following code:

```ts
/* my-handler.ts */
type MessageHandler<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (payload: T[K]) => void;
}

export interface Payload {
    Message1: {
        foo: string;
    };
    Message2: {
        bar: string;
    };
}

export type MessageType = keyof Payload;
export type MyHandler = MessageHandler<Payload>;

const myHandler: MyHandler = {
    Message1(payload) { console.log(payload); },
    Message2(payload) { console.log(payload); },
};

export default myHandler;

/* my-handler.test.ts */
const makePayload = <T extends MessageType>(type: T, str: string): Payload[T] => ({
    Message1: { foo: str },
    Message2: { bar: str },
})[type];

const testCases: MessageType[] = ['Message1', 'Message2'];
testCases.forEach(messageType => {
    myHandler[messageType](makePayload(messageType, 'str')); // <-- error
});
```

The JavaScript for this clearly works, and everything compiles until I try to call `myHandler[messageType](makePayload(messageType, 'str'));`

> ```
> Argument of type '{ foo: string; } | { bar: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'.
>  Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'.
>    Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'. (2345)
> ```

It appears it can't detect that `myHandler[messageType]` is the function associated with the payload for it.

Even if I go overboard on typing, I get a similar error:

```ts
testCases.forEach(<T extends MessageType>(messageType: T) => {
    const handler: MyHandler[T] = myHandler[messageType];
    const payload: Payload[T] = makePayload(messageType, 'str');
    handler(payload);
});
```

> ```
> Argument of type 'Payload[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'.
>   Type '{ foo: string; } | { bar: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'.
>     Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'.
>       Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'.
>         Type 'Payload[T]' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'.
>           Type '{ foo: string; } | { bar: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'.
>             Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ bar: string; }' but required in type '{ foo: string; }'. (2345)
> ```

Everything I've learned about TS tells me it should be at least able infer the relationship in the second one.  I don't understand why `handler()` is expecting `Message1 & Message2` instead of just the payload the function should expect.

Comment: This is another one for the growing pile of questions where the problem is that TS lacks support for what I've been calling "correlated union types", see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Realistically speaking you will want to use a type assertion and move on, since the only other way to do it is redundancy, which you don't want... see [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN5XMw) for the two options

Comment: Since this is test code, `as any` it is!